# laravel: working with PUT request

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4

I use resource controller in Laravel 4, as part of resource controller I must use `PUT` request method. it works fine for me when I have one form in the page.

the problem is that I divide my page to 3 peaces with 3 different forms.
If I `var_dump` my data I with `input::All()` I get following results.

When I update form2 I get `form2 data` - this what I want!

But when I update again `form1` for example I get data from `form2` and `form1`.

When I update again `form3` I get data from `form2` + `form1` + `form3`.

How can I get data only from the form I just updated? I tried to use `Input::get('form1');` but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using different forms for different things. Think of using Ajax requests from your page etc to send the fields that you require on certain button clicks. This way then you know you should only receive the data you want.

[Ajax Post Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: thanks, I already changed it, I use one form and send only specific section. the problem was that I don't clean my variable (the one I use to collect the data)